# Get ITaskbarList3 data of specific window

Tags: winapi, windows-7, taskbar, hwnd

[ITaskbarList3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface provides only setter methods. Is there a way to **get** the information (like HWND list of the tabs) for a specific taskbar entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not possible through the taskbar API. The system has been designed with the intention that you'll only work on taskbar buttons that you own. In which case there's no need for getters since you can remember for yourself what value you last passed to a setter, should you need to.

Comment: I will not really change the data, i need it for some debuging purposes. But because of your statement, i will think up something else. Thanks!

Comment: @XHelp I'm sure you wouldn't be so naughty, but plenty of other people would!!

Comment: I know it's quite an old topic but I wanted to know; how does only allowing setters PREVENT others modifying the tabs of other applications? I've just messed around with my windows explorer tab. Surely only providing getters stops people from modifying the information?