# ITaskbarList3 hook or replacement

Tags: winapi, windows-7, com, taskbar

I'm trying to create a Windows 7 taskbar replacement. Builtin taskbar has some nice features which I'd like to reimplement, specifically a progress bar hosted in a taskbar button ([ITaskbarList3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391698%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Since other applications communicate with system taskbar by obtaining its interface instance by calling `CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskbarList, ...)` I need either to replace COM-object CLSID_TaskbarList or setup some sort of hook for `ITaskbarList3::SetProgressValue` and `ITaskbarList3::SetProgressState` to be able to show progress on my own window. Any ideas how to do this?

(It's not the same as [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330355/get-itaskbarlist3-data-of-specific-window))

Comment: Found some [magic](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14040/Hooking-a-DirectX-COM-Interface) but still looking for better solution.

Comment: Since all apps have you go through `CoCreateInstance()` to reach `ITaskBarList` and descendants, simply create your own COM object that implements the `ITaskBarList` interfaces as needed and then register it using the existing `CLSID_TaskbarList` class ID. What's so hard about that? If you ever want to uninstall your COM object, you better remember Microsoft's original class ID so you can restore it later.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your reply. I think the replacement of system COM-server is generally not a good idea.
More over I'd like to minimize registry "intervention" and i'd like to have an ability to coexist with system taskbar if possible.
At the moment I'm looking into hooking CoCreateInstanse with [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/)